# How to store the data as dictionary from a text file that has n number of entries that belongs to different items

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file that contains records of n people as shown below.

```
name=Ramesh
age=20
uid=15762gfyf
EOM

name=Tom
age=20
uid=15762gfyd
EOM

name=Gavin
age=25
uid=15762gfyz
EOM
```

I need to write a code in python such that the input and output are shown below

input:
uid= 15762gfyz
output:
age=25

I can do this if the record of each person is in one single file but here the file contains n number of different records.The file is provided as the input to the code hence there is no manual intervention.I am not sure if this can be achieved using a two dimensional list or else the dictionary.

I've tried the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print('Please enter the absolute path of the file')

path = input()
i = 0
my_dict = {}
content = open(path)
contentEntries = content.readlines()
for entries in contentEntries:
if entries != 'EOM':
    entries[i] = entries.split('=')
    i = i + 1
    my_dict['entries[i][0]'] = 'entries[i][1]'
else:
    break
```

Could someone please help me with the logic to store the file and then compare it with the given input to provide the corresponding output.

Comment: I have tried the below but not sure if I am moving in the correct direction or not      #!/usr/bin/python3
  2 
  3 print('Please enter the absolute path of the file')
  4 
  5 path = input()
  6 i = 0
  7 my_dict = {}
  8 content = open(path)
  9 contentEntries = content.readlines()
 10 for entries in contentEntries:
 11    if entries != 'EOM':
 12       entries[i] = entries.split('=')
 13       i = i + 1
 14       my_dict['entries[i][0]'] = 'entries[i][1]'
 15    else:
 16       break

Comment: can you post the same in your question and as code formatted?

Comment: Copied code from the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

with open('foo.txt') as f:
    entities = f.read().splitlines()

parsed_entities = []
while entities:
    props = itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n != 'EOM', entities)
    entity = dict(p.split('=') for p in props)
    entities = entities[len(entity)+2:]  # Delete and skip EOM & newline
    parsed_entities.append(entity)
```

Comment: Hey Infinity.Thanks for the response. I have not tried this yet so shall try it and will let you know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

@gahan

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print('Please enter the absolute path of the file')

path = input()
i = 0
my_dict = {}
content = open(path)
contentEntries = content.readlines()
for entries in contentEntries:
   if entries != 'EOM':
      entry[i] = entries.split('=')
      i = i + 1
      my_dict['entry[i][0]'] = 'entry[i][1]'
   else:
      break
```